# Eloquent Model Events in Laravel 5.1 Testing Environment

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, eloquent, laravel-5

I have an `Eloquent` model for which I have some observer methods defined in the model's `boot()` method. It's a very simple logic - I use the `creating()` static method to define a default value for an attribute if it hasn't been defined when calling `Model::create([...])`.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function (Content $content) {
        static::setDefaultValues($content);
    });
}

protected static function setDefaultValues(Content $content)
{
    if ( ! $content->published_at) {
        $content->published_at = Carbon::now();
    }
}
```

It all works fine when working with the app via browser, or console using `artisan tinker`, or the database seeder.

However, when I try to use the same database seeding logic to bootstrap the testing database via an artisan command when the test case runs, I'm getting exceptions thrown saying that particular attribute can't be NULL. I did a bit of research and digging through Laravel code, and saw that the Event Dispatcher should be functioning normally since I'm not mocking any events nor using `withoutEvents()` helper.

Also, global scopes don't seem to apply properly in the testing environment.

I've placed var_dumps on several critical points (immediately after call to `creating()`, inside `Eloquent\Model` class in the `save()` method and after model events are fired) to inspect the attributes and noticed that observer methods *are* being executed, but the effect is as if model instances are not being passed by reference to event handlers, but cloned. The same code runs properly in development environment, but fails as described in testing environment.

Has anyone encountered something like this? I'm not really sure how to proceed, so any advice is very welcome.

For what it's worth, I'm using MySQL in development and trying to run tests in a SQLite database for ease of use. The tests are being run with Laravel's out-of-the-box PHPUnit testing setup.

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of all model event bindings to AppServiceProvider::boot() method, like below

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \App\Content::creating(function (Content $content) {
            $content::setDefaultValues($content); // change to public
        });

        // other bindings
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Follow http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events

You can use that method also to attach model observers.

Comment: is possible tu use more generic? for example with Model class??

Comment: I've tried to use a BaseModel class and call BaseModel::creating but not works

Comment: I don't think so, because the event dispatcher uses the model class name to format the event name. look at Model::fireModelEvent($event). So, "eloquent.creating User" not matches "eloquent.creating BaseModel".